# Pancakeswap BNB Staking contract not pending balance on Polygon Mumbai

Tags: pancakeswap, polygon, staking

Im trying to port over Pancakeswap BNB Staking to Polygon. So Instead of BNB staking id like to support MATIC staking.

I have WMATIC contract, reward token contract and BNB Staking from pancakeswap. They are all deployed to Mumbai (Polygon testnet) but still after a deposit I cant see pending rewards.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the BNBStaking contract address on Polygon Mumbai:
[Address of Polygon Mumbai EtherScan](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x07f7ac69a6449f725bfcdbf8b3fb52e78251311c#code)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and it was on my deployment script.

The reward amount I set per block was too low, so on my deployment script I edited this amount with the right value in WEI. After that everything was solved.

Below find the snipptet with the fix

```
  await hre.run("verify:verify", {
    address: lafinca.address,
    constructorArguments: [
        wmatic.address,
        mangoToken.address,
        '1000000000000000000',
        24640195,
        30000000,
        "0xb8AF02b8b712b6eB9dD05Abc4A9dc68ffC8C4c7c",
        wmatic.address
    ],
  });
```